# call an json array data in db using a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I have a db whose values are as follows:[image: img] Can I call the json value of listing_id(23,27....so on) in properties column(with having row value as "listing") using a single query, I would
Really Appreciate the help .

Comment: What do you mean by **calling** i.e. any way I can call that using an sql query

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.7 or newer? You can use the built-in JSON functions to parse `properties`.

Comment: how ?? im using sqllite

Comment: Do you mean you want to select rows based on the value held in the JSON data held in the `properties` row

Comment: Why do you have the tag `mysql` if you're using `sqlite`?

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly that is exactly what i want to do. I am using  sqlite in this table

Comment: But where is this table held. MySQL or SQLite

Comment: SQlite. --@RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the [JSON extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_function) is installed, yes you can, using `json_each`. That is a table_valued_function so it is treated like a table.

You may want to execute `SELECT * from ahoy_events,json_each(properties)` in sqlite browser to get a feel for the data.

Something like:

```
SELECT value as listing
from ahoy_events,json_each(properties)
where key = 'listing_id'
```

should list the id (value)

[EDIT]

If the JSON extension is not available, you could try using [SQLite core functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) `substr`, `instr`, and `length`.

The value portion of the properties column is seen between the `:` and the `}`. The `:` is at position `instr(properties,':')`.

`substr(properties,instr(properties,':') + 1,length(properties)-instr(properties,':') - 1)`

From the doc, "*The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long.*'

Y is `instr(properties,':') + 1`, ie the character after the `:`.
Z is `length(properties)-instr(properties,':') - 1)`

You can use the `substr` in a SELECT or a WHERE.

Another thought: If the `properties` column is always single valued, as the data seems to show, mightn't it be easier to only insert the "value" into the properties column in the database? Or add a new `listing_id` column. That approach would work with data structured as shown, it can't be known to me how production data would be structured.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting this error..... "near "(": syntax error Unable to execute statement"....when executed the query in Sqlite Studio.Am I Missing something...or ...is there any other way

Comment: JSON extension not available? Dunno. You could also parse it out of the `properties` column with [substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr). Equally effective, more typing.

Comment: It sounds like you accepted the answer but did not have success. That is very generous and I thank you. I have added more info to the answer 1) specifics on the substr approach and 2) a thought about changing the database contents. Good luck,